# Can you use sql like() functions for table joins?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have two tables, each with a single string column (name).  I'd like to do a left outer join from t1 to t2 where t1.name like %t2.name% or t2.name like %t1.name%

is something like that possible?

Comment: but indexes will not work if you have `%` in the front of search string

Comment: I'm actually just putting the % on the end, but thanks for the info.

Comment: `LIKE` is a predicate, not a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much anything that goes in a `where` clause can also go in an `on` clause, like:

```
select  *
from    t1
left join  
        t2
on      t1.name like '%' + t2.name + '%'
        or t2.name like '%' + t1.name + '%'
```

Comment: you got the second like back-to-front. Should be `t2.name like '%' + t1.name + '%'`

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You can do it like this:

```
... where t1.name like '%' + t2.name + '%'
```

Comment: what is the role of || here? can u elaborate.

Comment: You can use pipes to concat (like in Oracle) if you have `set sql_mode = 'PIPES_AS_CONCAT';`

Comment: I want to find any entries where one name starts with the other, for example - Jeff would join with Jeffrey, and Jeffrey would join with Jeff - I'm guessing it's (t1.name like t2.name+'%') or (t2.name like t1.name+'%').

Answer (score 2):

Yes. From the MySQL docs on [JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

> The conditional_expr used with ON is any conditional expression of the
>   form that can be used in a WHERE
>   clause.

Answer (score 1):

As Andomar pointed out, there's not much difference between an `on` clause and a `where` clause.

However, using `like` on a join would be a bad practice in most scenarios, as it can (and will) lead to unexpected results. E.g, if the two tables have rows with names `A, Ab, Abc` and `Abcd`, the resulting left join will not have just **4** rows, because it will match basically every row from the first table with every for from the second table, and you'll get **16** results, instead of 4.

Comment: Thanks - I'm joining on other columns and using the like condition to refine the join.

Comment: Yes, the `likes` might save you when the data is kinda-sorta consistent, but do think if there are scenarios that might cause duplicate results.

Comment: I see what you're getting at, I'm using rails so I can refine the results at in the framework code.